# How do you get the UISearch view to return values from a switch statement to the DVC?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I would like to know if the `searchcontroller` can push results to the `detailviewcontroller` from a switch statement.

Here is how I have my app currently set up.

.h

```
@interface MOVTableViewController : UITableViewController {

    NSMutableArray* filteredList;

    IBOutlet UISearchBar *search;
}

@property(strong, nonatomic) NSArray *lodgeList;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSArray *cityname;



@end
```

.m

```
    #import "MOVTableViewController.h"
    #import "MOVDetailViewController.h"

    @interface MOVTableViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation MOVTableViewController

    @synthesize lodgeList, cityname;


    - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
    {
        self = [super initWithStyle:style];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];


        //Start of Lodge List

        lodgeList = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:

                     //Abingdon
                     @"Abingdon Lodge No. 48",
                     @"York Lodge No. 12",

                     //Alberene
                     @"Alberene Lodge No. 277",

                     // Alexandria
                     @"A. Douglas Smith, Jr. No. 1949",
                     @"Alexandria-Washington Lodge No. 22",
                     @"Andrew Jackson Lodge No. 120",
                     @"Henry Knox Field Lodge No. 349",
                     @"John Blair Lodge No. 187",
                     @"Mount Vernon Lodge No. 219",......

    filteredList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:lodgeList];

    //end of list

}
    - (void)viewDidUnload
{

    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [filteredList count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    cell.detailTextLabel.text =[cityname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.textLabel.text = [filteredList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}


- (void) searchTableView
{

    filteredList = nil;

    filteredList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:lodgeList];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF like[c] %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@*",search.text]];
    [filteredList filterUsingPredicate:predicate];
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    [self searchTableView];


}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *) searchBar
{
    [self searchTableView];
    [search resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [self searchTableView];
    [search resignFirstResponder];
}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"lodgedetail" sender:self];
    }
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender

{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"lodgedetail"]) {
        MOVDetailViewController *MDVC = segue.destinationViewController;

        NSIndexPath * path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSString * thelodge = [filteredList objectAtIndex:path.row];

        MDVC.lodgeName = thelodge;
        MDVC = [segue destinationViewController];
        MDVC.lodgeNumber = path.row;


        NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;

        if ([self.searchDisplayController isActive]) {
            indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            MDVC.lodgeName = [filteredList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


        } else {
            indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            MDVC.lodgeName = [filteredList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


        }
    }


}



@end
```

.h (detail View)

```
@interface MOVDetailViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *address;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *website;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *statedc;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *lodgehistory;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * lodgeName;
@property int lodgeNumber;

@end
```

.m (detailView)

```
#import "MOVDetailViewController.h"

@interface MOVDetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation MOVDetailViewController


@synthesize address, lodgeName, lodgeNumber, lodgehistory, statedc, website;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];



    self.title = lodgeName;

    switch (lodgeNumber) {
        case 0:
            //Abingdon Lodge No. 48
            address.text = @"325 W Main Street Abingdon, Virginia 24210";
            website.text = @"http://www.grandlodgeofvirginia.org/lodges/48/";
            statedc.text = @"Abingdon Lodge No. 48 holds it's stated communication on the 2nd Monday of the month at 7:30 PM. If there are any exceptions to the regular meeting day or time, they are posted on the Lodge website.";

            lodgehistory.text = @"According to the earliest records the Abingdon Lodge had its origin “At a meeting held at the house of James White in the town of Abingdon, on October 3, 1796.” The record states that a dispensation had been given by the Grand Master of Masons in Virginia and the following were present: William King, Master; Daniel Murphy, Past Master; Robert Johnson, Past Master; Charles Carson, Past Master, and William Preston Skillern. For more information on the Lodge History please see the Lodge website.";

            break;


            //York Lodge No. 12
        case 1:
            address.text =@"14411 Black Hollow Road Abingdon, Virginia 24210";

            website.text = @"http://www.grandlodgeofvirginia.org/lodges/12/";

            statedc.text = @"York Lodge No. 12 holds it's stated communication on the 4th Monday of the month at 7:30 PM. If there are any exceptions to the regular meeting day or time, they are posted on the Lodge website.";

            lodgehistory.text = @"York Lodge No. 12 was chartered on December 16, 1885. This Lodge was formed from a disturbance in Spring Creek Lodge No. 173, which was disbanded. The meetings were held in a schoolhouse at Maple Grove, Virginia on the second floor. The second floor caved in at some time and the meetings were then held on the first floor. In 1957 the Lodge voted to remodel the building for the cost of approximately five thousand dollars. In 1979 the December stated meeting was held in a new building that cost twenty thousand dollars. The fellowship hall is used by the Lodge, its members and the community for Church meetings, family functions, wedding dinners, arts and crafts and more. York Lodge is a part of its community and the community is a part of York Lodge.For more information on the Lodge History please see the Lodge website.";
            break;

            //Alberene Lodge No. 277
        case 2:
            address.text = @"2722 Plank Road Alberene, Virginia 22959";

            website.text = @"http://www.grandlodgeofvirginia.org/lodges/277";

            statedc.text = @"Alberene Lodge No. 277 holds it's stated communication on the 2nd Monday of the month at 7:30 PM. If there are any exceptions to the regular meeting day or time, they are posted on the Lodge website.";

            lodgehistory.text = @"Alberene Lodge No. 277 was chartered in 1900. The Lodge was destroyed by fire September 20, 1933, and the charter was reissued October 6, 1933. The 1 3/4 acres of land was purchased from Alberene Store Co. deeded August 25, 1937.  The first meeting place was over a store building about two miles from the present location.  Membership ranges from 40 to 60 members. The Lodge has remained small in number, but large in fellowship and real meaning in Masonry. It seems the Lodge will never go anywhere, by that it is meant never grow big or do anything great. By what all of the members have gained, the members will keep the Lodge in the best of Masonic health. For more information on the Lodge History please see the Lodge website.";
            break;


            //A. Douglas Smith, Jr. Lodge of Research No. 1949
        case 3:
            address.text = @"101 Callahan Drive Alexandria, Virginia 22301";

            website.text = @"http://www.grandlodgeofvirginia.org/lodges/1949/index.asp";

            statedc.text = @"A. Douglas Smith, Jr. Lodge of Research No. 1949 holds it's stated communication on the 5th Saturday of the month at 10:00 AM. If there are any exceptions to the regular meeting day or time, they are posted on the Lodge website.";

            lodgehistory.text = @"This Lodge of Research, the second in Virginia, was established in 1982. While there were several distinguished Masons in Northern Virginia who were instrumental in establishing the Lodge, the primary organizer was Most Worshipful Stewart W. Miner, Past Grand Master. He was most ably assisted in this effort by the District Deputy Grand Master of Masonic District No. 1A, Right Worshipful Werner H. Morlock, and Right Worshipful John H. King, Chairman of the Grand Lodge Committee on Lodge Development. Right Worshipful Christopher Dains and Worshipful William A. Myers, Past Master of Springfield Lodge No. 217 also provided assistance. Brother Morlock eventually served as Grand Master of Masons in Virginia in 1993-1994, but died in office before his term was completed. Worshipful Brother Myers became the first Worshipful Master of this Lodge. For more information on the Lodge History please see the Lodge website.";
            break;
```

The reason Im asking is because after I preform a search and click on one of the results, the `detailviewcontroller` does not update the `IBOulets` `UItextview` for address, websites, static or history. It continues to show the first lodge. however If I DO NOT preform a search the DVC preforms fine and updates all the information accordingly.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `prepareForSegue` method, why are you reinitialising the view controller variable? Try to remove the line as mentioned in the code below:

```
MOVDetailViewController *MDVC = segue.destinationViewController;
NSIndexPath * path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
NSString * thelodge = [filteredList objectAtIndex:path.row];

MDVC.lodgeName = thelodge;
MDVC = [segue destinationViewController];  // REMOVE THIS LINE
MDVC.lodgeNumber = path.row;
```

---

Please try this updated `prepareForSegue` method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"lodgedetail"]) {
        MOVDetailViewController *MDVC = segue.destinationViewController;

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;
        if (self.searchDisplayController.isActive) {
            indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            NSLog(@"filteredList = %@", filteredList);
            MDVC.lodgeName = [filteredList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            // ******* Find row from the "lodgeList" array *******
            for(int i = 0; i < [lodgeList count]; i++) {
                if([MDVC.lodgeName isEqualToString: [lodgeList objectAtIndex: i]]) {
                    MDVC.lodgeNumber = i;
                    break;
                }
            }  

        } else {
            indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            MDVC.lodgeName = [lodgeList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            MDVC.lodgeNumber = indexPath.row;
        }
        NSLog(@"indexPath = %@", indexPath);
    }
}
```

Comment: Print value of `lodgeName` and `lodgeNumber` at the end of `if` condition in `prepareForSegue` and before `switch` statement. See if they are being assigned properly

Comment: printf(lodgeList) returns the following errors and I am unable to run the app. ARC Restrictions, Semantc issue, format string issue, and parse issue.

Comment: you need to print value using `NSLog("lodgeList = %@", lodgeList);`

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please try this `prepareForSegue` method

Comment: Step closer, its now changing in order of the filtered list, but still not the correct lodge. for example when searching for lodges that start with K, it shows all the lodges with k. Then after clicking on the 1st lodge the return result is Abingdon. The 2nd K lodge returns the 2nd lodge in the table which is York Lodge No. 2.. so on an so forth. Im not sure this is going to work. because of the way I have coded the app.

Comment: Hi I have updated my answer. The reason you are not getting the correct value is because when you are `searching`, you should find row number from the `lodgeList` array and NOT from the `filteredList` array (as highlight in my answer)

Comment: For example, when searching `car` you get correct result in the table view. But then you assign `lodgeNumber = 0` when you select row `Carter Lodge Number 323`. What you need to do is find row number from `lodgeList` array and assign that to `lodgeNumber`

Comment: Hello user42.... Thanks for the help. I have tried the above answer and after preforming the search and clicking on a table cell, nothing happens. The cell is highlighted and thats it.

Comment: Have you checked `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method? Does it go to `prepareForSegue` ?

Comment: ok, not sure what I did on the first try, must of did something wrong. I tried it again and got the following.

Comment: 2012-11-21 22:19:18.049 Masons of Virginia[4483:c07] indexPath = <NSIndexPath 0x76a8d10> 2 indexes [0, 3]
2012-11-21 22:19:22.738 Masons of Virginia[4483:c07] filteredList = (
    "Liberty Lodge No. 95",
    "Lake Drummond Lodge No. 178",
    "Liberty Hall Lodge No. 104",
    "Lancaster Union Lodge No. 88",
    "Lebanon Lodge No. 251",
    "Lafayette Lodge No. 137",
    "Linn Banks Lodge No. 126",
    "Lakeland Lodge No. 190",
    "Lynnhaven Lodge No. 220",
    "Lee Lodge No. 209"
)
2012-11-21 22:19:22.739 Masons of Virginia[4483:c07] indexPath = <NSIndexPath 0x72fb9e0> 2 indexes [0, 0]

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"lodgedetail" sender:self];
    }
}

Comment: Did you get the correct output? Did you worked on getting the correct row number at `// ******* Find row from the "lodgeList" array *******` in my answer

Comment: User427969 Im new so Im not sure how to do that can you contact me via my blog at www.appswecode.com please.

Comment: Once you get the hint of how things work, you should do it by yourself.

Comment: I will. Thanks again. I just start coding in July. Its my first of many apps to come... Im going to study what you just gave me. Ill also spend the rest of the night playing around with it as well to learn how it works. Have a Happy Thanksgiving!